# How to combine values based on standard errors?

Tags: mean, standard-error

Let's assume we have two means with corresponding standard errors.

```
mean_1 = 3.75, se_1 = 0.64
mean_2 = 2.90, se_2 = 0.94
```

I would like to average the means and account for the standard error. I would like `mean_1` to contribute more (since the standard error is lower) to the average than `mean_2`. A weighted mean if you will.

One way would be to specify weights as the relative magnitude of the standard error like so (I use R's function `weighted.mean` found in the base `stats` package):

```
> weighted.mean(c(3.75, 2.0), w = c((1 -0.64/(0.64+0.94)), (1- 0.94/(0.64+0.94))))
[1] 3.041139
```

Does that make sense? How would one go about this problem? I would be happy to hear your critiques and suggestions.

Comment: Use the Delta-method ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you believe that these two means are both estimates of the *same true value* then [inverse-variance weighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting) is the way to go. That's equivalent to [*fixed-effect* meta-analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis#1._Fixed_effect_model).

If you believe that the means are estimating *different* true values, then things get more tricky. If there were more means, you could do [*random-effects* meta-analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis#2._Random_effects_model). In principle that still works with only two means, but your estimate of the between-sample variance will be very imprecise. A fully Bayesian analysis would put an informative prior on the between-sample variance.

Comment: (+1) 1: there is no evidence of a significant difference in means, so your first suggestion looks applicable. 2: the reason for using inverse-variance weighting is that this is the minimum-variance unbiased estimate of the mean.